# Is there a more efficient way to check whether one line ends with another line in a large file

Tags: scala, large-files, ends-with

I have a file with 500,000 lines and I want to check for each line *L* whether any other line in the same file ends with *L*.

I have already sorted the file by the length of the lines and have written the following code but it is to slow:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))
    val fw = new FileWriter("output.txt")
    var line = buffer.readLine()
    var list = List.empty[String]
    while (line != null) {
      if (line.nonEmpty) {
        list += line
      }
      line = buffer.readLine()
    }
    buffer.close()
    list = list.sortBy(s => s.length)
    for (i <- list.indices) {
      val endsWith = list(i)
      for (j <- i + 1 until list.size) {
        val right = list(j)
        if (right.endsWith(endsWith)) {
          fw.write(list(j) + ";" + list(i) + "\n")
          fw.flush()
        }
      }
      println(i + 1)

    }
    fw.close()
  }
```

The input file contains such entries like:
abc/defg
defg
...

**Is there a more efficient way to check the lines?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem by using the length of each line *L* and extract this length from the other lines. Afterward, I hash *L* and the extracted strings and store them in a hash map. Finally, I check whether the map contains the query hash. As soon as two lines have the same length I need only to check the hash in the map, this saves me a lot of overhead. I also used the idea from talex to reverse each string before hashing.

Here the code for the solution:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"))
    val fw = new FileWriter("output.txt")
    var line = buffer.readLine()
    var map = Map.empty[Int, List[String]]
    while (line != null) {
      if (line.nonEmpty) {
        val len = line.length
        map += len -> (map.getOrElse(len, List.empty[String]) ++ List(line.reverse))
      }
      line = buffer.readLine()
    }
    buffer.close()
    val list = map.keySet.toList.sorted
    for (i <- list.indices) {
      val len = list(i)
      var cutMap = Map.empty[Int, List[String]]
      for (j <- i + 1 until list.size) {
        for (right <- map(list(j))) {
          val took = right.take(len)
          cutMap += took.hashCode -> (cutMap.getOrElse(took.hashCode, List.empty[String]) ++ List(right))
        }
      }
      for (startsWith <- map(len)) {
        val hashCode = startsWith.hashCode
        if (cutMap.contains(hashCode)) {
          for (right <- cutMap(hashCode)) {
            fw.write(right.reverse + ";" + startsWith.reverse + "\n")
            fw.flush()
          }
        }
      }
      println(i + 1)
    }
    fw.close()
  }
```

If the hashCode function is not precise enough it can be replace by a more precise one. For bigger files the algorithm could be separated to work with file splitting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort file in specific way.

Try next algorithm:

1. Revers each line.
2. Sort list.
3. Go thru list and for each adjacent pair and check if shorter is beginning of longer.

Comment: This approach reduces the search for the beginning of the comparison but is still too slow. Is there a hashing algorithm or something that enable a more efficient comparison?

Comment: I doubt it is possible to do better in terms of `O`, in practice it depends on distribution of your data. There is no obvious optimization.